# Jquery Datatables won't return hidden fields value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i have a table defined, this is the code

```
$('#tblData').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        'url': url,
        'type': "POST",
        'contentType': "application/json",
        'data': function () { return JSON.stringify(json); },
        "dataSrc": "register"
    },
    searching: false,
    paging: true,
    select: true,
    bInfo : true,
    lengthMenu: [3, 5, 10],
    columns: columns
});
```

this table has a set of columns defined in as follows:

```
var columns = [
{ "title": "IDUSER", "data": "idUser" },
{ "title": "NOMUSER", "data": "nomUser" },
{ "title": "IDCITY", "visible": false, "data": "idCity" },
{ "title": "IDSTORE", "visible": false, "data": "idStore" }
```

];

when i try to read the value of a hidden column, i get an undefined response

this is the function i use to access the data from the table

```
function getTableContents(_idTable) {
var table = $("#" + _idTable).DataTable();
var responsearray = [];
var tableData = table.rows().every(function (index)
    {

        var user = {
            idUser: table.row(index).data()["idUser"],
            nomUser: table.row(index).data()["nomUser"],
            idCity: table.row(index).data()["idCity"],
            idStore: table.row(index).data()['idStore']
        };
        responsearray.push(user);
    };
);

return responsearray ;
}
```

idUser and nomUser are returned withouth a problem, but idCity and idStore aren't.

the documentation isn't very helpful and i am at my wit's end. what could i b doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Are you getting values for visible columns? And please try to get values using index like `idUser: table.row(index).data()[0]`

Comment: A little bit peculiar setup. You create the table, then iterate over the rows to construct the exact same structure as your data...?  If that is what you want, you can simply use `table.data()` ...`table.row(index).data()` *will* return hidden values, as long as you not actively indicate that you not want those values, so you have something else going on. Try to see if you can replicate the behaviour in a fiddle

Comment: mmushtaq: i tried using the index value table.row(index).data()[0] wwith no success,

Comment: davidkonrad: i did this since the normal table().rows().data() didnt returned hidden values,  searching in this site i found that you need to explicitly define the index of the hidden column, but for that i need to iterate through its contents. as for the fiddle, i dont know how to build it, but when its ready i will publish it